# Menu doesn't open on mobile

Tags: menus, themes, mobile

I'm developping a website and I have the following issue:

I am using version 5.1.1 of WordPress with the latest version of the [Phlox](https://wordpress.org/themes/phlox/) theme and the [Elementor](https://elementor.com/) page builder version 2.5.10.

I use the vertical menu. The menu doesn't show on mobile. The hamburger menu appears but when you click on it, the menu does not appear. It works fine on a full desktop screen or tablet. I set it as primary menu but this did not resolve the issue.

It did work with another header layout (horizontal).

Comment: It looks like it's set up to be two different menus: the normal vertical menu has CSS class `aux-phone-off` that hides it in mobile mode, and this menu is separate on the page from the burger menu, which is empty. So I guess the problem is that you need to duplicate the menu options in the burger. I don't know the theme or plugin to know which one is at fault here. Maybe you just need to configure the options in two places, or it should be possible to write some code to modify one to read the list of options from the other.

Comment: Hey Hilde, welcome to WordPress development. Please don't include links to your site. What value does this link have as soon as your issue got fixed? Apart from that, your question isn't WordPress-specific at all. It's a CSS issue which should better be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks Rup!!  I 've changed the burger menu location from left to right and now it shows the menu in mobile mode.